# How can I replicate an existing data warehouse on Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-warehouse

I am new to Azure and have no prior experience or knowledge regarding working with Azure data warehouse systems (now Azure Synapse Analytics Framework)

I have access to a "read only" data warehouse (not in Azure) that looks like this:

[image]

I want to replicate this data warehouse as it is on Azure cloud. Can anyone point me to the right direction (video tutorials or documentation) and the number of steps involved in this process? There are around 40 databases in this warehouse. And what if I wanted to replicated only specific ones?

Comment: Is this using a dedicated or serverless SQL pool. If it is a dedicated pool then this article from Microsoft should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/backup-and-restore

Comment: I forgot to mention that the existing warehouse is not on Azure

Comment: @IronMaiden we can't do that you only have the read only permisson! No matter which data warehouse, we all need the server admin or database owner permission to do the database replicate.

Comment: @LeonYue can you please provide a documentation regarding this (permission aspect)?

Comment: @IronMaiden you can get this on all the documents relate to the database backup/migrate/replicate, for example:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions

Comment: @IronMaiden you're welcome, may I post the answer?

Comment: @LeonYue Sure you can but also if you can please provide a solution if the login access were given. Given that the data warehouse I want to replicate on Azure is located on a different server (i.e., not on Azure)

Comment: @IronMaiden Sorry, a little confused, do you mean you want replicate the Azure datawarehouse to on-premise server? The question shows the on-premise SQL Server datawarehouse, what's the Azure resource, Azure SQL database or SQL pool (formerly SQL DW) like blockingHD said?

Comment: @LeonYue The replication is the other way round. I want to replicate an on-premise server to Azure data warehouse.

Comment: @IronMaiden I need confirm with you again that  replicate an on-premise server to SQL pool (formerly SQL DW)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't do that you only have the read only permisson. No matter which data warehouse, we all need the server admin or database owner permission to do the database replicate.

You can easily get this from the all documents relate to the database backup/migrate/replicate, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions,

If you have enough permission then you can to that. But for Azure SQL datawarehouse, now we called SQL pool (formerly SQL DW), we can't replicate other from on-premise datawarehouse to Azure directly.

The official document provide a way import the data into to Azure SQL pool((formerly SQL DW)):

- Once your dedicated SQL pool is created, you can import big data with
  simple [PolyBase T-SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?toc=/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/toc.json&bc=/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true), and then use the power of the
  distributed query engine to run high-performance analytics.

You also could use other ETL tool to achieve the data migration from on-premise datawarehouse to Azure. For example using [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction), combine these two tutorials:

1. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Synapse Analytics by using Azure
   Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)